# How to configure Oracle ODP.Net to bring all rows in a single round-trip?

Tags: .net, oracle, performance, odp.net

I'm having some poor performances on different scenarios using client and Oracle on different machines, even with low latency, and I checked that configuring `OracleDataReader.FetchSize¹ = OracleDataReader.RowSize * {number-of-rows}` (before first `Read()`), I get better results depending on `{number-of-rows}` value, at cost of memory.

This differences only happen when testing in different machines. When testing in  localhost, the performance still nearly identical. I guess because even with multiple round-trips to the database, there is no network involved and Oracle is using another protocol (I guess IPC) aside from TCP.

To clarify things, lets check this example:

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table"; // any query

        using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Configure FetchSize and vary {number} to get performance results
            dr.FetchSize = dr.RowSize * {number}; // Must be configured before first Read()

            Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); // To check the elapsed time

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                object[] values = new object[dr.FieldCount];
                dr.GetValues(values);
            }

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed); // Print the time elapsed to read all data
        }
    }
}
```

If the query returns 1000 rows each with 10 bytes (RowSize), then FetchSize with 10 * 1000 (FetcSize = RowSize * {number-of-rows}) would be the ideal value, so the client only needs one round-trip to the database to get (fetch) all the data. If FetchSize = 10, the client would need to go 1000 times to the database to get all the data, each time getting only 1 row.

If the query returns just 10 rows with 1 bytes each, then FetchSize = 10 would get better performance (10 * 1) because the client only needs one round-trip to the database.

In my tests, I got some scenarios (eg: queries with ~90k rows) that using FetchSize as default (= 128kb = 131.072) takes ~12.6s and using FetchSize = 10000 * RowSize takes 1.6s!

So, FetchSize depends on the query estimated number of rows and the medium size of row (aka `OracleDataReader.RowSize`).

So I got into 2 ways to think of a solution:

1. Let the DB decide how many rows do fetch at once (hence something like `FetchSize = -1` similar to other configurations likes `InitialLOBFetchSize = -1`')
2. In a generic way, I need to make a good strategy for estimating how many rows the query will return and configure `{number}` with it.

   - In this case, I'm thinking about use some database statistics to find it out, but I'm certain that the database should know and use it (or let us choose for it to use) really simpler than an application developer could do (aka it must have a way to let the database choose the  best option).

It's important to say that, for my scenario, I always read all the rows and the network between client and database are with very low latency (<1ms).

**So, my question is: how do I achieve case 1? What I need to configure to make ODP.Net Oracle fetch all rows in a single round-trip to get better performance results?**

Notes:

¹ `OracleDataReader.FetchSize` defines how many bytes the client gets from the database at a single round-trip (aka trip trough client -> database -> client).

References:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featData.htm#ODPNT302
- https://books.google.com.br/books?id=AsSBza2KxogC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=oracle+fetchsizer+retrieve+all+rows+at+once&source=bl&ots=Y7U87tE8g7&sig=RZB4wPXQOgeUgqzCmFISdA9QBCc&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwist_Cyj_DVAhVKi5AKHY9hAHYQ6AEIZTAI#v=onepage&q=oracle%20fetchsizer%20retrieve%20all%20rows%20at%20once&f=false
- https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/bip/BIPDM/best_practices.htm#BIPDM530

Comment: "If the query contains too much rows, than a bigger {number} get good results, but if it has few rows, we have poor results." Can you clarify this statement because it sounds like you are saying *the* query finishes faster when it returns more rows than when it returns fewer rows. To me that implies the two executions used different execution plans.

Comment: How do you determine the RowSize?

Comment: @jeff6times7 the query execution time is the same (hence, it's the same query), I'm only comparing the fetch time from the database rows to the client with different `OracleDataReader.FecthSize` values that determines how many bytes are get in a single round-trip from the client to the database.
I'll rewrite the description. Thanks.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit from `OracleDataReader.RowSize`

Comment: I think now would be a good time for you to modify your post to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we'll probably end up spending too much time interviewing the answers to our questions.

Comment: @jeff6times7 tried to rewrite the question and explained using an example showing code. Now I guess it's clearer. Check it, please. Thanks.

Comment: You're getting there. Now add the instrumentation code where you're seeing one execution being faster than another.

Comment: @jeff6times7 oh well, its a simple Stopwatch... I'll add.

Comment: You told us earlier that you are comparing only the time it takes to transport the rows from the RDBMS user process to your app (something I doubted). The timing calls you just added cover dr.Read(). The Read method covers nearly all of the work performed the RDBMS server process to produce the rows that will be transported. The code you show allows for the possibility that the two executions have different execution plans. You can prove they have the same plan by showing the plh value of the first FETCH dbcall for the statement found in the extended SQL trace file for both executions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152838/discussion-between-iuri-dos-anjos-and-jeff6times7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon Oracle's architecture, you will never be able to implement your #1 solution (i.e., telling Oracle to figure out how to minimize or eliminate wasteful network round trips).

But you *might* be able to partially implement #2. Your success will depend upon (a) your ability to determine the largest number of *average* rows that will fit into a single `Send Data Unit (SDU)` which is probably 2048 bytes and (b) the data fetched conforming to the model you define in a.

Knowing that there is an SDU constraint and that Oracle fetches complete rows is key to optimizing network activity.

I recommend you take into account the SDU when you effectively set the array fetch size (i.e., the number of complete rows fetched per fetch operation) by executing `FetchSize = RowSize * {number-of-rows}`.

If the resulting FetchSize consistently causes too many extra network round trips (see the trace data), then you need to increase or decrease FetchSize until you're satisfied that there is no other single FetchSize that further reduces wasteful network round trips for a given data reader object.

If you anticipate there is too much analysis that it is likely to be invalidated over time as the data changes, then I recommend you fetch between 100 and 1,000 rows per fetch operation for all of your SQL statements depending only on the OracleCommand's estimated rowsize. If the rowsize is small, then fetch 1,000 rows per fetch. If the rowsize is really big, then fetch 100 rows per fetch.

This should insulate your app from the egregious examples I see regularly with my customers who have this type of problem. It won't be perfect but at least you won't have to overanalyze the problem and the resulting code won't have to change.

Below is my attempt to elaborate if any is needed.

Oracle is architected such that the client is forced to fetch a number of complete rows at a time. The client driver therefore, will never be allowed to hand control to the app giving it an incomplete row.

The worst type of example of wasted packets would be for the app to fetch "select 'x' from millionRowTable" one row at a time (by setting fetch size to row size). This will result in 1,000,000 network round trips. It's amazing how often I visit customers who don't even know they have the problem or that it can exist. In this example, you'll see something like this repeating 1,000,000 times in the trace data:

```
 WAIT #1: nam='SQL*Net message from client' ela= ...
 WAIT #1: nam='SQL*Net message to client' ela= ...
 FETCH #1:c=1999,e=1243,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=1,...
```

where, r=1, is showing one row fetched for each network round trip. The two trace file WAIT lines are indicating a read finished and a write began. In other words, the pair indicate a network round trip.

A less painful example is when you set the array size to a value that results in an payload that is slightly larger that what Oracle can fit into a single SQL*Net packet. Let's say you fetch 200 rows at a time from "select uniformlyTenByteRow from millionRowTable" and the only way you could get a single round trip to contain all 200 rows would be if the SDU were 2056. Because of this unfortunate combination, you see something like this repeating 5,000 times in the trace data:

```
WAIT #1: nam='SQL*Net message from client' ela= ...
WAIT #1: nam='SQL*Net message to client' ela= ...
WAIT #1: nam='SQL*Net more data to client' ela= ...
FETCH #1:c=19999,e=12433,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=0,r=200,..
```

The `more data to client` WAIT line indicates one additional network round trip. You might have expected 5,000 network round trips but you actually got 10,000 network round trips. Ten thousand network round trips to fetch 1,000,000 small rows is not horrible but it could be better.

Comment: Thanks. I've made some tests and setting {number} with 100 or 1000 already gave good results, so there's no point of wasting more time to get few milliseconds or even less.

Comment: That's how we generally see it play out in real life. You do a little bit of work to determine a "good enough" array fetch size for a given query (it's going to be different for different queries), and "good enough" actually is good enough. ...And it's usually far better than the default, so it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you should preferably estimate the number or rows based on your application logic. You don't need the exact number, just the magnitude should match.

You can estimate number or rows based on Oracle execution plan. Before you execute your query run statements like this:

```
DELETE FROM PLAN_TABLE;
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM table;
SELECT CARDINALITY
FROM PLAN_TABLE
WHERE ID = 0;
```

`ID = 0` refers to the top line of execution plan, i.e. cardinality of entire statement.

For better performance you may run such procedure only once (for each query) at application start-up and keep the number in memory.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that. But I want to get it in some generic way that I can use in my application for every procedure/query. Dont know if its possible yet.

Comment: One of the problems with this approach is that the `EXPLAIN PLAN` command will not always reveal the row source operations that will actually be used. Another problem is that the rows estimated is only an estimate. Obviously, if the SQL statement is always of the form "select * from table" with no `WHERE` clause and table is a real table, then you might as well query ALL_TABLES.NUM_ROWS to get the results from the last table analyze. But if no analyze was performed or if it's sufficiently stale, then relying upon the estimate becomes more troublesome.

Comment: Yes it is an estimate but better than nothing. If your statistics are not up to date then the Oracle optimizer has problems anyway and you may have poor performance due to that.

Comment: Well, I did some tests considering {number} as the number of rows returned (just to check performance results) and the costs of memory was too high on large query results. In one of the tests, my machine just crashed. So, I guess for now, it's a lot simpler to fix it at 100 or 1000 to get good results without too much effort.

Comment: The full curve relating response time to array fetch size is a bathtub. See an example on page 5 of https://method-r.com/2011/08/01/making-friends/.